# Regular Expression to remove every whitespace which is not after a comma

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

i want to replace remove/replace every whitespace in a string which is not after a comma.
I already searched for a suitable regex but i did not find one.
Here is a sample of the strings i want to modify:

```
{id=565189.0, server=Ealyn, merchantName=Nox, activeMerchants=[{id=f01b617d-2dc7-4597-2297-08dabad9a125, name=Nox, zone=Nebel horn, card={name=Bergstrom, rarity=2.0}, rapport={name=Energy X7 Capsule, rarity=3.0}, votes=0.0}]}
```

should change to (_ trough replace)

```
{id=565189.0, server=Ealyn, merchantName=Nox, activeMerchants=[{id=f01b617d-2dc7-4597-2297-08dabad9a125, name=Nox, zone=Nebel_horn, card={name=Bergstrom, rarity=2.0}, rapport={name=Energy_X7_Capsule, rarity=3.0}, votes=0.0}]}
```

Can someone with a high knowledge then me over regular expression's create one for this case?
Thanks in advance

I already tried this expression:

```
(^|[^,])\\s+
```

.. but it always removed a character with the whitespace

Comment: maybe you could match a whitespace with a lookbehind for NOT commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!,)\\s+
```

The Output:

```
{id=565189.0, server=Ealyn, merchantName=Nox, activeMerchants=[{id=f01b617d-2dc7-4597-2297-08dabad9a125, name=Nox, zone=Nebel_horn, card={name=Bergstrom, rarity=2.0}, rapport={name=Energy_X7_Capsule, rarity=3.0}, votes=0.0}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. The trick is to choose the group you want to keep and reference it in the replacement parameter of the `replaceAll` method.

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var before = "{id=565189.0, server=Ealyn, merchantName=Nox, activeMerchants=[{id=f01b617d-2dc7-4597-2297-08dabad9a125, name=Nox, zone=Nebel horn, card={name=Bergstrom, rarity=2.0}, rapport={name=Energy X7 Capsule, rarity=3.0}, votes=0.0}]}";
    var after = before.replaceAll("([^,])\\s+", "$1");
    System.out.println(before);
    System.out.println(after);
  }
```